# CakePHP How to echo just one record

Tags: cakephp, echo, record

I want to echo a full name from my MySQL database in my header. When that name is clicked in a list it filters all the records and displays all the records related to that name only.  I managed to get the filter working, but not able to display the name in header.

```
<? $this->read('$jobs as $row'); ?>
 <h1><?=$row['Employee']['first_name']?> <?=$row['Employee']['last_name']?>'s Jobs</h1>
<? $this->end(); ?>
```

Comment: If you query your database and echo the result in the same place, you are not using the MVC concept that CakePHP offers. Maybe you want to restructure this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you are trying to retrieve this array, I'm assuing **$jobs** contains single row.

try this

```
<?php 
if (isset($jobs)) {
foreach($jobs as $row){ 

if (isset($row['Employee']['last_name']))
     $last = $row['Employee']['last_name'];


$first = 'N/A';
if (isset($row['Employee']['first_name']))
    $first = $row['Employee']['first_name'];
?>

 <h1><?php echo $first.' '. $last?>'s Jobs</h1>    
<?php } }?>
```

OR

```
  <h1><?php isset($jobs[0]['Employee']['first_name']) ? $jobs[0]['Employee']['first_name'] : 'N/A' .' '. isset($jobs[0]['Employee']['last_name']) ? $jobs[0]['Employee']['last_name'] : 'N/A'?>'s Jobs</h1>
```

Comment: Oh, one more thing.  It works only if there is a record but if there is NO record for a particular user it shows up with this:  Notice (8): Undefined variable

Comment: for that you need to add isset while echo result

Comment: For some reason it's still coming up with the same error if there is no record of jobs for a particular name.

Comment: Notice (8): Undefined variable: row [APP/View/Jobs/employee_filter.ctp, line 2]

Comment: I am so sorry about this...  It's still the same situation only a different line:  Notice (8): Undefined variable: last [APP/View/Timesheets/employee_filter.ctp, line 15]

Comment: <?php foreach($jobs as $row); ?>

    <?
     if (isset($row['Employee']['last_name']))
     $last = $row['Employee']['last_name'];


     $first = 'N/A';
     if (isset($row['Employee']['first_name']))
     $first = $row['Employee']['first_name'];
    ?>

    <h1><?php echo $first.' '. $last?>'s Jobs</h1>

Comment: I suppose I can just make sure there is some sort of job data for each employee to keep the error away for now.

Comment: please see my answer carefully, i have updated this one before.

Answer (score 0):

This can be much more easily achieved through the use of virtual fields. The example in the Cake book is practically identical to your needs.

Just add this to your Employee model:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'full_name' => 'CONCAT(Employee.first_name, " ", Employee.last_name)'
);
```

Now [Employee]['full_name'] can be used without having to use any logic.

Here's the link to the Cake book page covering virtual fields: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html